# Быстрое создание нескольких однотипных уровней (Сцен) в Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Есть первая рабочая сцена игры в 2D проекте Unity, где уже можно делать то, что задумывалось. Уровень проходится за очень небольшой промежуток времени. Теперь нужно сделать ещё пару десятков похожих сцен с добавлением чего-либо. На сцене есть пустые объекты со вложенными в них другими объектами. Были созданы префабы самых "Высших" объектов, в которых всё вложено. Я думал, что получится просто взять и переместить туда этот префаб со всеми дочерними объектами, в которых есть компоненты, требующие ссылок на другие компоненты, но поместить нужный объект в переменную, к примеру, GameObject lol, не получается, т.к. префаб не выходит за рамки "себя" и не видит другие нужные префабы. Получается, что чтобы всё заработало на новой сцене, нужно заново перетаскивать все компоненты на новой сцене в переменные всех скриптов.

Можно ли этот процесс ускорить? Есть ли та волшебная кнопка, которая позволит мне моментально скопировать объекты, у которых есть объекты, в которых есть скрипты, требующие ссылки на другие объекты?

Comment: Используйте [DontDestroyOnLoad](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.DontDestroyOnLoad.html)

Comment: Если уровни можно выбирать (загрузка схожих уровней происходит не последовательно), то в этом случае это ведь не поможет

Comment: И в чем же? Можно проверить id сцены и понять, что оставить, что уничтожить.

Comment: Есть много сплсобов, уточните что за объекты... много, мало, однотиптые или нет.

Comment: а Ctrl+C => Ctrl+V сцены не вариант?

Comment: @Yaroslav, 7 родительских родительских объектов, в каждом из которых от 2-х объектов, на каждом из которых есть 1-2 скрипта, в которых есть переменные, в которые нужно вставить другие объекты. То есть, почти все объекты связаны друг с другом

Comment: @Yaroslav, и ещё однотипных объектов на сцене только 2, остальные - уникальные, каждый из которых отвечает за что-то своё. Но в новых уровнях будет больше однотипных объектов

Comment: @Арман, если выбор уровня осуществляется с главного меню, на котором нет нужных объектов, то что тогда?

Comment: @Methorn, в редакторе не было такой функции, поэтому я думал, что нужно куда-то залезать, чтобы провернуть такое, что есть какая-то кнопка неизвестно где, позволяющая дублировать сцену. Оказалось, что можно просто копировать и вставить сцену через проводник

Comment: @MarkMa Ctrl+D - дублирование объектов и прочих штук

Comment: @Methorn, понятно. Спасибо